# Errors when Removing a Layout from a Laravel 5.2 Project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am running into a problem removing layouts from a Laravel 5.2 project.

I removed the layout from its directory and all references to it from related views. Now, when I redirect to those views, I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [layouts.projectCreate] not found.
```

After doing a search for any lines of code that contain references to the projectCreate layout, only three turn up. They all share a directory and have identical code. Here's an example:

```
C:\laravelproject\storage\framework\views\448aadb5ef486de8fc3cd6cd8f229de3303bd234.php:
   75  
   76  <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
   77: <?php echo $__env->make('layouts.projectCreate', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

Laravel seems to be retaining unwanted references to the offending layout. What is the correct course of action to get this layout out of my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove view, you should make sure you don't have any other views cached using this view. The best way to do that is running:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

It will remove all compiled views so they will use up-to-date code for compilation